# iOS-Charts StackedBar value display

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am using iOS-Charts for one of my project, I have created `StackedBar` chart using the library.

I have few question related to setting the values.

- Is it possible to show the value of selected Stack Index only?
- How to retrieve the value of specific stacked item. e.g. right now I am getting `ChartDataEntry, xIndex: 7, value 75.0`, where 75 is the total of all the stacked value, I have 3 stack item and their vales are 20, 50 and 5. How can I get values like this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Youn need to use the delegate to control how you want to highlight and show the value. Take a look at ChartsDemo and maybe rewrite the highlight method to do it. Should be easy
2. there is `values` to get each one, and `value` is the sum

   ```
   public var values: [Double]?
   {
       get { return self._values }
       set
       {
           self.value = BarChartDataEntry.calcSum(newValue)
           self._values = newValue
           calcPosNegSum()
       }
   }
   ```